# The spy failed to start. Could not select a developer identity (certificate)

Tags: ios, xcode, automation

I'm using the Quamotion WebDriver to script a test on an iOS device.

I get an error message when I start the test, as well as when I start the Spy in the WebDriver interface.

I've attached a screenshot of error in the Spy, my Python test script and the result.

What am I doing wrong?

**Error Information**
The spy failed to start. Could not select a developer identity (certificate) and a provisioning profile to launch 'Quamotion Device Agent' on the device with UDID '232133a9b7b5a840d4da4dc2a8f45cd492633a9c'.

```
import quamotion

driver = quamotion.device('232133a9b7b5a840d4da4dc2a8f45cd492633a9c')
apps = quamotion.get_installed_apps()
print(apps)

driver.implicitly_wait(60000)

driver.home_screen()

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Safari').click()

urlTextField = driver.find_element_by_class_name('XCUIElementTypeTextField')
urlTextField.clear();

urlTextField.send_keys('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id304878510')
urlTextField.send_keys('\n')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label='GET']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label='INSTALL']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label='OPEN']").click()

driver.switch_to_alert().accept()

driver.quit()
```

```
   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 903, in implicitly_wait
    'ms': float(time_to_wait) * 1000})
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stacktrace:
    at Quamotion.WebDriver.Controllers.SessionController+<SetImplicitWaitTimeout>d__42.MoveNext (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (<anonymous>)
    at lambda_method (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable+Awaiter.GetResult (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+AwaitableResultExecutor+<Execute>d__0.MoveNext (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (<anonymous>)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker+<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0>d.MoveNext (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker+<<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0>d.MoveNext (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (<anonymous>)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (<anonymous>)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0>d.MoveNext (<anonymous>)
```

```
Resign Information
Provisioning Profile Elegibility
Profile Rejected Reason Preferred Reason    Selected?
Dist Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch   Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - My JBL Headphones   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
HarmanDisTest   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch AppIdSeedMatches    false
LexiconSoundsteer Dist Profile  Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dist Prov Profile - My JBL Headphones   Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Enterprise_DebugSoundsteer_developerment    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate  HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
App Store HKController  DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Harman Kardon Citation AppStore Profile DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
BigData JBL Connect Dev Prov Profile    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - HK Controller   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.BLETool   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist Prov Profile - JBL Connect Expired, NoCertificate  AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch   false
Dev AKG N20LT   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Harman Kardon Citation AppStore Profile DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Dev My JBL Headphones   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev HK Controller   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Sherlock In-house Dist Prov Profile Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
Dist Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch OS1   Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.iapTest   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist Prov Profile - JBL Connect None    AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch   false
iOS Team Inhouse Provisioning Profile: com.harman.BLETool   AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate    AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dev Prov Profile for Sherlock   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Harman Test Dev Profile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - AKG N20LT   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist AKG N20LT  AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
App Store AKG N20LT Headphones  DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
enterprise_soundsteer_dev   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate  HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist Prov Prof - JBL Music Test Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - HK Connect Plus Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
Dist Prov Profile for Sherlock  Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.aaaaaUITests  AppIdMismatch   HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.WXDemoUITests DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Connect AdHoc Profile   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate None    false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect DeviceIdMismatch    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Dist Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch OS2   Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
HK Citation Dist Profile    Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - HK Controller   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Provision Profile (Dist) JBL Smartbase  DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.BLEDemo   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate  HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
BigData JBL Connect Dev Prov Profile    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - My JBL Headphones   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Prov Prof - JBL Music Test  Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - My JBL Headphones   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Harman Test Dev Profile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
BigData JBL Connect Dev Prov Profile    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Connect Distribution    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate None    false
Dist HK Headphones  AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Harman Automation Dev Profile   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev - JBL Music DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Harman Test Ad Hoc Profile  Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate AppIdSeedMatches    false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.WXDemo    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman..Playtime DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate  HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch OS2    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Harman BLETools DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Harman BLETools DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
HarmanEnterprise Test Dist Profile  AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate    AppIdSeedMatches    false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
IT Service Desk Mobile  Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
JBL Connect Distribution    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate None    false
Dev Harman How-To-Listen App    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
HK Headphones App Store Provisioning    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.CrashDemo DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Dist harman bluetooth tools AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dev Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch OS2    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate  HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Big Data JBL Connect Dist Prov Profile  Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Harman Enterprise Test Dev Profile  DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Developer Provisional profile - HK Connect Plus Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist - JBL Music    AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dev Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch OS2    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.iapTestUITests    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist Prov Profile - HK Connect Plus Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
HkRemoteJune2018ProvProfile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.BeetStudio.AWS-DA-SDK    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Harman Test Dev Profile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - My JBL Headphones   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch OS1    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Music Dev Profile   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL DSP amplifier Dist profile  Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate None    false
Dev Harman How-To-Listen App    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
Dev HK Headphones   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Nixoa Mobile APP    Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Harman Test Ad Hoc Profile  Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dist Prov Prof HK Remote    Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.aaaaa AppIdMismatch   HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
HK Citation Dev Profile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dis JBL PartyBox    AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dev JBL PartyBox    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
JBLConnect  DeviceIdMismatch    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
HarmanDevTest   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Harman Test Dev Profile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
QQMusic_Profile_4_D_And_M   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow false
Dist Prov Profile - HK Controller   Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Sherlock In-house Dist Prov Profile Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - AKG N20LT   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate  None    false
Dist My JBL Headphones  AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dist Prov Profile - AKG N20LT   Expired, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Dist JBL Connect    None    AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch, MatchesEmbeddedProvisioningProfile   true
Dist Harman How-To-Listen App   AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
LexiconSoundsteer Distribution Profile  Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate None    false
iOS Team Inhouse Provisioning Profile: com.harman.test  AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
Dist HK Controller  AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.test  DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist Prov Profile - JBL Connect Expired, NoCertificate  AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch   false
Developer Provisional profile - AKG N20LT   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist Prov Profile - JBL Connect Expired, NoCertificate  AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch   false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.playtime  DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Prov Profile for Sherlock   Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch OS1    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Prov Prof - JBL Music Test  Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.RatingSDK AppIdMismatch   HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
iOS Team Inhouse Provisioning Profile: com.harman.playtime  AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
HkRemoteJune2018ProvProfile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dist Prov Profile - JBL Connect None    AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch   false
Dev Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
iOS Team Inhouse Provisioning Profile: com.harman.iapTest   AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
JBL Connect Distribution    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Big Data JBL Connect Dist Prov Profile  AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Developer Provisional profile - JBL Connect Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
JBLConnect  Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, NoCertificate    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
Appstore JBL PartyBox   DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Dist Harman tools   AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
App Store HK Headphones DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
App Store JBL BAR Setup DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Harman Kardon Citation AppStore Profile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate None    false
JBL Headphone App Store 2020    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch None    false
Harman Test Dev Profile Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.harman.BLEDemoUITests    DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate  HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev Prov Profile - HK Controller Apple Watch    Expired, DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch, NoCertificate HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev HK Connect Plus DeviceIdMismatch, AppIdMismatch HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches   false
Dev JBL Connect DeviceIdMismatch    HasGetTaskAllow, AppIdSeedMatches, AppIdExactMatch  false
Dist Harman How-To-Listen App   AppIdMismatch   AppIdSeedMatches    false
Certificate Elegibility
Certificate Rejected Reason Preferred Reason    Selected?
Apple Distribution: Harman International Industries (94V8DBZ242)    None    None    false
Apple Development: 肯 刘 (KN2HV3FSRM) None    None    false
Apple Development: 肯 刘 (KN2HV3FSRM) None    None    false
iPhone Distribution: Harman International Industries Incorporated   None    None    true
iPhone Developer: 肯 刘 (KN2HV3FSRM)  None    None    false
Apple Distribution: Harman International Industries (94V8DBZ242)    None    None    false
Apple Distribution: Harman International Industries (94V8DBZ242)    None    None    false
```

Comment: You have a ` Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` problem. See the source line tags within your output to where in your code files this refers to.

Comment: The error message indicates that you don't have a provisioning profile or a code signing certificate which you can use to resign iOS applications and install them on your device. Did you upload your developer profile to the WebDriver? If so, can you share a screenshot of the Settings page?

Comment: @FrederikCarlier, I post a screenshot in your email,  thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please type out and quote the complete error message in your question, not post an image. That way future people with the same problem will be able to find this question.

Answer (score 2):

In the Spy window you can click on "More information about how this application will be resigned." (after selecting type, Platform, Device, ...)

The resign details give you information why the provisioning profile or certificate is rejected/accepted.

Could you copy the content of this window?

Comment: I posted the content of that page.

Comment: @JackChen I cannot find the resign information. Could you post it in text, to avoid the image to be deleted?

Comment: I put up all the information on that page. Is there anything I left behind?